# How to set required unless flag using clap in Rust

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

So I am trying to write an implementation of *cp* using Rust but I am stuck in a problem. There is a flag `-t=DIRECTORY` and the usual `DESTINATION`. I am stuck in this here, if the `-t` option, `DESTINATION` should not be provided but if `-t` is not given `DESTINATION` must be provided. Also there is `SOURCE` flag which is both required and multiple

Comment: Just... check it by hand after parsing? clap can't built-in a hook for every possible permutation of everything, but nothing stops you from writing code doing that for your ad-hoc behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen an option for this in clap, I will suggest you do it by yourself. I mean using clap to parse argument and manually throw an error if both parameters found.